# Does memory effect preformance or lot of if conditions effect?

Tags: java, performance

Can any one please suggest best Performance code between these two code snippets

**Code 1**

```
       Map token_map = new HashMap();
        for (int i = 1; i < req_tokens.length; ++i) {
            String[] spl_token = null;
            spl_token = req_tokens[i].trim().split("=");
            token_map.put(spl_token[0], spl_token[1]);
        }

        cs_chnl_id = (String) token_map.get("ChannelId");
        obj_id = (String) token_map.get("ObjectId");
        channel_name = (String) token_map.get("ChannelName");
        username = (String) token_map.get("Username");
        pwd = (String) token_map.get("Password");
        hotel_key = (String) token_map.get("Channel_hotel_key");

        resId = (String) token_map.get("Res_Id");
        String booking_date = (String) token_map.get("Booking_Date");
        days_past = (String) token_map.get("Days_past");
```

**Code 2**

```
            for (int i = 1; i < req_tokens.length; ++i) {
                String[] spl_token = null;
                String key = null;
                spl_token = req_tokens[i].trim().split("=");
                key = spl_token[0].trim();
                // initilizing cron values for instance varibles
                if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("ChannelId")) {
                    cs_chnl_id = spl_token[1].trim();
                } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("ObjectId")) {
                    objectId = spl_token[1].trim();
                } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("ChannelName")) {
                    channel_name = spl_token[1].trim();
                } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Username")) {
                    username = spl_token[1].trim();
                } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Password")) {
                    pwd = spl_token[1].trim();
                } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Channel_hotel_key")) {
                    hotel_key = spl_token[1].trim();
                } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Res_Id")) {
                    resId = spl_token[1].trim();
                } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Booking_Date")) {
                    booking_date = spl_token[1].trim();
                } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Days_past")) {
                    days_past = spl_token[1].trim();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Well, you could try both on the same input data and see which one runs faster…

Comment: Why don't you first start with readability, and then consider performance - which approach do *you* think is better?

Comment: @MarounMaroun In code 1 I am saving the values in Map (token_map) and assigning to string variables , in code 2 i am not using Map(token_map) , hope you got my point

Comment: Don't waste your time with the performance, a tactical way is, first make it runnable than make the code sexy and high performance valueable

Comment: The first one would be even better, if you don't use a raw type map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), insertion and lookup operations have time complexity of O(1), they'll have almost the same performance, but the first code is *much* more readable, don't waste your time about performance, go with the first.